# ePUB 3.0 File Structure

Tags: xml, xhtml, epub, epub3

If an ePUB 2.0 is like this:

```
folder/
    META-INF/
        container.xml
    mimetype
    OEBPS/
        content.opf
        toc.ncx
        [etc]
```

Then is there any difference between what is shown above in ePUB 3.0, or is the structure the same as 2.0? IDPF has doumented 3.0 decently well, but they do not explicitly state this obvious question. IBM has an excellent "ePUB from Scratch" for 2.0, but the current 3.0 tutorial is unhelpful.

Answer (score 2):

The structure is the same, though note that with epub 3.0 you'll also need a toc.xhtml for navigation. You can include the toc.ncx as well, for backwards compatability. More info is available [here](http://www.idpf.org/epub/30/spec/epub30-publications.html#ncx-superseded).

Answer (score 2):

The directory/file hierarchy inside an EPUB container is arbitrary, except for:

- `mimetype` (must be in the root of the container)
- `META-INF/container.xml` (must be as exactly at this path)

All the other files might be anywhere inside the EPUB container (but not inside the `META-INF` directory).

In short: the indication you are asking for is not present in the EPUB specification because the structure inside the EPUB container is up to the EPUB producer. The one you wrote in your question is just one example, but it is not mandatory.